# Accessing an offline SVN repository

Tags: svn, repository, local, offline

I have an SVN repository that is currently offline due to a router failure. It's going to be a few more days before it is fixed, but I need to use the repo NOW. I can possibly put the repo on a USB key, but then what can I do with it to update/commit ?

Can I easily run a copy of the repo on my machine, do some /etc/hosts changes to take care of redirection ?

Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I did the following:
On the SVN server I recovered the repository:

```
$ svnadmin dump MyRepo > /media/UsbKey/MyRepo.dump
```

Then on an accessible temporary server where I already had apache I installed svn and imported the repository:

```
yum install subversion mod_dav_svn
nano /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-subversion.conf
mkdir /var/www/SVN
svnadmin create MyRepo
svnadmin load --force-uuid MyRepo < /media/UsbKey/MyRepo.dump 
htpasswd -cm /etc/svn/svn-auth MyUser
ln -s /etc/svn/svn-auth /etc/subversion/passwd
chown -R apache /var/www
```

Then I added the IP of the new server with the name of the old one to /etc/hosts of the SVN client PCs and they kept working seamlessly.

I'll do the reverse procedure once I get the old server back online. Maybe there was a simpler way, but all in all it didn't take too long.